# Screen time statistic for longer periods

Tags: screen-time

The screen time feature is awesome!

However, having only daily or weekly statistics is a bit limiting.

Is there any way to see usage for a longer time, like the last month?

Alternatively: does anyone know where the log files are stored on the file system so I can parse them myself? As iOs even keeps deleted Photos forever, I assume the log files for screen time are also kept somewhere.

Comment: You're asking 2 distinct questions.  This site works best in answering 1 question at a time.  I would recommend that you [edit] and splitting your question into two.  The question about the logs has already been asked, but not yet answered, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346091/is-there-a-way-to-download-screen-time-data-from-iphone-or-other-apple-ios-devic?rq=1).